# Preventing symbols from different layers from interfering with each other in ArcGIS online

Tags: symbology, arcgis-online

I am tackling a project that contains several new elements for me since I am a high school social studies teacher and not a full-time GIS professional.

For this particular project I am trying to show the various US interventions during the Cold War around the world.  I have created individual points for each intervention.  These points are in a shapefile that contains a list of 49 different interventions.  The fields include the country of the intervention, the year, a short description and whether or not a certain type of action occurred.

Example:  Guatemala, 1954, (description) and the following values for the six types of action possible: Command=1, Troops=0, Bombing=1, Naval=0, Nuke=1, Jets=0.  What this means is that in 1954 we used Command Operations, Bombing and Nuclear Threats to intervene in Guatemalan affairs.  On this particular point then I would like to see the three distinct symbols for those types of action.  Currently I can achieve this by creating 6 layers but the symbols are all stacked on top of each other.

This has all been done in Desktop 10.1 Advanced.  I plan to create a feature service on our AGOL account once I have solved this problem.

Thanks for any advice.